# How to pass an argument to the C++ application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, arguments

In Java you can pass an argument with `void main(String[] args)`.

Find `run configuration` in Eclipse, put arguments and run a program, but in C++ there is just `int main()` how to pass arguments to the program using Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While `int main()` is correct, you can use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` to get the argument count with `argc` and an array of char arrays (strings) with `argv`.

Please note that the first argument will always be the path to the program you are running.

Answer (score 2):

It'you can refer to any basic c++ programs in any tutorial for this.

```
argc- number of argument count
argv- argumant list
```

Below is sample code to parse argument list.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
  {
  cout << "The name used to start the program: " << argv[ 0 ]
       << "\nArguments are:\n";
  for (int n = 1; n < argc; n++)
    cout << setw( 2 ) << n << ": " << argv[ n ] << '\n';
  return 0;
  }
```

If you are using visual studio there is a command line property using which you can pass commandline parms

Answer (score 1):

**Sample code :**

```
// command_line_arguments.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main( int argc,      // Number of strings in array argv
          char *argv[],   // Array of command-line argument strings
          char *envp[] )  // Array of environment variable strings
{
    int count;

    // Display each command-line argument.
    cout << "\nCommand-line arguments:\n";
    for( count = 0; count < argc; count++ )
         cout << "  argv[" << count << "]   "
                << argv[count] << "\n";
}
```

Read more about argument parsing in c++ read [Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx) in MSDN. there are example input output also.